# Find the continued fraction digits of $\sqrt{3+i} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, continued-fractions

We can show that $\sqrt{3+i} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$ without too much effort, e.g. by solving $$(x+yi)^2 = (x^2 - y^2) + (2xy)i = 3+i$$  Therefore, we can try to find approximations, using only rational elements of the field.  What are the continued fraction digits

$$ \sqrt{3+i} = [a_0;\overline{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n}] \in \mathbb{C}$$
with $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. I'm quite sure they repeat.

Even the first digit, I wonder how we can compute it?
$$ \lfloor \sqrt{3+i}\rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}[i] $$
We could solve an equation of some kind perhaps $a^2 + b^2 < 3^2 + 1^2 = 10$.  Not too many solutions to that.

---

I guess, there's no "positive" $\sqrt{3+i}$ so I guess it's the one with positive real an imaginary part, something like $\mathbb{R}_{\geq}\oplus\mathbb{R}_{\geq}$.

Comment: Calculations really work. Wolfram Alpha link added.

Answer (score 5):

The floor of $\sqrt{3+i}$ isn't well defined (at least, at present, without thinking about it and giving it a definition). For that matter, neither is $\sqrt{3+i}$ (there are two of them). Thus your question as stated can't be answered without some clarification.

That said, let's think about how to define continued fraction expansions with entries in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ for a general complex number.

Let $a+bi$ be some complex number. What is the closest Gaussian integer to $a+bi$?
Well, let $n$ be the closest integer to $a$ and let $m$ be the closest integer to $b$.
Then $$|(a+bi)-(n+mi)|=(a-n)^2+(b-m)^2\le \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<1.$$

Thus we can call this Gaussian integer (which may not be unique) a floor of $a+bi$. The floors of a complex number have the important property that $|z-\newcommand\floor[1]{\left\lfloor {#1}\right\rfloor}\floor{z}|<1$, so we can then do the usual continued fraction expansion, by recursively defining
$$z_0=z, \quad a_i = \floor{z_i},\quad\text{and }z_{i+1}=\frac{1}{z_i-a_i}.$$
Then we should have
$$z=a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\cdots}},$$
probably. There's some stuff to check here, with convergence and all that, but it should probably work the same as with the real numbers and the integers.

Note however that the coefficients aren't necessarily unique, and this continued fraction expansion won't necessarily be as nice as it is for the integers.

Apparently I've described the [Hurwitz algorithm](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dhensley/SanAntonioShort.pdf) for complex continued fractions, described in more detail in the linked paper.

Answer (score 0):

Continued fraction are defined for $x\in\mathbb R_+$ and can be calculated via the Euclidean algorithm, i.e. integer division.

Complex numbers can not be compared to "less" and "greater", so the operation of integer division is not defined on $\mathbb C.$ This possibility can be defined only for special subsets of $\mathbb C.$

Therefore, in the Hurwitz decomposition algorithm, instead of integer division, rounding is used independently for real and imaginary parts.

Let us find the point $a(x,y)\in \mathbb Z_i,$ the square of which is the nearest to $3+i.$

Attempt of approximation using norm
$$N=|a^2(x,y)-(3+i)|$$
[cannot guarantee N < 1 for the considered example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2-y%5E2-3)%5E2%2B(2xy-1)%5E2%20%3C1).

[image: Complex continued fraction]

More perspective looks preliminary square root extraction,
$$r(s,t) = \sqrt{3+i},$$
$$s^2-t^2 + i(2st) = 3+i,\quad s^2+t^2 = \sqrt{10},$$
$$s^2=\dfrac{\sqrt{10}+3}2,\quad t^2=\dfrac{\sqrt{10}+3}2,\quad 2st=1,$$
with the solutions
$$r=\pm(s+it),\quad s=\dfrac{\sqrt{\sqrt{40}+6}}2\approx1.75532,\quad 
t = \dfrac1{2s}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\sqrt{40}-6}}2\approx0.284849.$$

For the "positive" root [Wolfram Alpha gives continued fraction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(3%2Bi))
$$r=[2; \{-2 - 2i, 4\}]$$
(using the Hurwitz expansion).

How does it work?
$$a_0 = [\Re r+0.5]+i[\Im r+0.5] = 2,$$
$$r_1 = \dfrac1{r-a_0} = \dfrac{(r-a_0)^*}{|r-a_0|^2}= \dfrac {s-2-i t}{(s-2)^2+t^2},$$
$$r_1 =  \dfrac{\sqrt{\sqrt{40}+6}-4}{2(4+\sqrt{10}-2\sqrt{\sqrt{40}+6})} - \dfrac{\sqrt{\sqrt{40}-6}}{2(4+\sqrt{10}-2\sqrt{\sqrt{40}+6})}i \approx -1.73523 - 2.02008 i,$$
$$r_1=\dfrac1{\sqrt{3+i}-2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3+i}+2}{-1+i} = -\dfrac{1+i}2(\sqrt{3+i}+2)$$
$$a_1 = [\Re r_1+0.5]+i[\Im r_1+0.5] = -2-2i,$$
$$r_2 = \dfrac1{r_1-a_1} = \dfrac{(r_1-a_1)^*}{|r_1-a_1|^2}= \dfrac {s+2-i(t+2)}{(s+2)^2+(t+2)^2},$$
$$r_2=-\dfrac2{(1+i)(\sqrt{3+i}-2]}= -2\dfrac{\sqrt{3+i}+2}{(i+1)(i-1)} = \sqrt{3+i}+2\approx3.75532+i0.284849$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bs,t,%20(s-2-it)%2F((s-2)%5E2%2Bt%5E2),%20s%2B2%2Bit%7Dwhere%20s%20%3D%20sqrt(sqrt40%2B6.)%2F2,%20t%3D1%2F(2s))).

Easily to see that
$$a_2=a_0+2,$$
and that the denominator $r_2-a_2$ repeated.

Comment: This is wrong. Euclidean algorithm works just fine in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. You compare norms of elements rather than the elements themselves. (-1)

Comment: And if you're just being unclear, you should be able to adapt that to divide a general complex number by an element of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @jgon This doesn't mean $z_1 < z_2.$

Comment: Yes, the complex numbers aren't an ordered field, but I don't see how that prevents us from finding some analog of continued fraction expansion. Also on reflecting further, I'm not really sure what the Euclidean algorithm has to do with finding continued fraction expansions of irrational real numbers in the first place.

Comment: @jgon The OP definition does not provide convergency. I see only strange unproved ideas. Can you propose me some links?

Comment: Yes, the OP's question is in many ways unclear, and many unproved assertions are made, but your answer is also confusing and (on the surface, at least) appears to make false statements.

Comment: @jgon I don't see specific arguments. So I can claim that your downvote are based on the emotions, intuition or other illegal things.

Comment: Sorry, are you confused about my first three comments? In that case I'll try to be more clear. Continued fractions are defined for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$. Secondly they aren't calculated by Euclidean algorithm except for continued fractions for rationals. Thirdly, while the complex numbers aren't an ordered field, that doesn't mean that they don't have a norm (which is most certainly relevant here). Fourthly, integer division is perfectly well defined on $\Bbb{C}$, whatever you happen to mean by that. Since you mention the Euc. alg. for some reason. I'll point out that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is Euclidean.

Comment: If you didn't mean that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ doesn't have a division algorithm, then you can always find a Guassian integer within norm 1 of any complex number, and that allows for finding what is essentially the floor of that complex number. Which is really what's relevant for computing continued fractions anyway.

Comment: Hopefully these comments have made it a bit more clear what problems I have with your answer.

Comment: @jgon Then comment [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2-y%5E2-3)%5E2%2B(2xy-1)%5E2+%3C1), please. What about norm $1?$

Comment: You're solving $|z^2-(3+i)|<1$, note $|z-\sqrt{3+i}|<1$. Look at the countour plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Csqrt(3%2Bi)-(x%2Byi)%7C)

Comment: essentially 2 is within one unit of $\sqrt{3+i}$.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I will remove my downvote if you fix the problems with your answer. As long as it is mathematically correct, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @jgon Thank you. Fixed.